# Foreign key referenced value used only once

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have this kind problem regarding sql:

```
Table 1: ID_1 (Primary Key) | NAME | LASTNAME | EMAIL...
Table 2: ID_2 (Primary Key) | NAME2 | LASTNAME2 | EMAIL...
```

Normally using constraints it is possible to make as column in TABLE 2 
(NAME 2 for example) as a foreign key for NAME the first TABLE 1.

The general relation would be one-many. That's one value from column NAME in TABLE 1 used many times in column NAME2 in Table 2.

Now what I want to achieve is that making the rule one-to-one, so I cannot have duplicated values of NAME from table TABLE 1 in TABLE 2.

Does it require triggers or it can be set by constraint when creating the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to achieve this:

1. [Create foreign key constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)
2. [Create unique constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html)

This can all be done while creating the table.

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (
  ...,
  name2 varchar(255),
  FOREIGN KEY (name2) REFERENCES table1(name),
  UNIQUE (name2)
);
```

If you already have the table, use [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) instead.

---

When trying to insert a row with value of `name2` that is already in a table, an error will be raised.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be set by constraint. You can have foreign keys and unique keys on the same field. The unique constraint will guarantee there is only one record with one reference to the primary table (from that foreign table)